# Как сделать скролл в родительском RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Как можно сделать скролл целого родительского `LinearLayout` в коде ниже? Скролл появляется в `WebView`, когда при прокручивании шапка из `ImageView-TextView-TextView` остается на месте, что занимает часть полезного пространства экрана.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/article_preview_picture_Activity_ImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_article_preview"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_article_preview"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_preview_header_Activity_TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/article_preview_picture_Activity_ImageView"
        android:text="@string/header_article_preview"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_preview_description_Activity_TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_preview_header_Activity_TextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/article_preview_picture_Activity_ImageView"
        android:text="Description article" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/article_view_webView"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_preview_description_Activity_TextView"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Получилось сделать скролл всего экрана через расположение внутри ScrollView всех необходимых к прокручиваию элементов:

```
<LinearLayout >

<ScrollView
    >

<LinearLayout
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        >


        <ImageView
             />

        <TextView
             />

        <TextView
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
       >

        <WebView
           >
        </WebView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте компоненту которая скрывает хидер: https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar/blob/master/samples-stock/src/com/manuelpeinado/fadingactionbar/demo/WebViewActivity.java

```
   FadingActionBarHelper helper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
        .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
        .headerLayout(R.layout.header)
        .contentLayout(R.layout.activity_webview);
    setContentView(helper.createView(this));
    helper.initActionBar(this);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City");
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, за полезный к использованию компонент. В моем случае, больше подошло решение через использование ScrollView (ниже)